# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: with struts 1.3+jax-ws with security+weblogic 12C

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, struts

I have get error **java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: 
loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) 
previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"** 
I have using Netbeans 8.0, Weblogic 12C, java 7 with struts 1.3 use jax-ws which is in spring 3.1

Comment: It looks like you're app is bundling a library that's conflicting with what weblogics using.

Comment: Thanks @JGlass. Can you tell me which  libraries from weblogics  are conflicting?

Comment: It looks to be the jar containing the QName in package path "javax.xml.namespace.qname".  There's a huge [list](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html) of a lot of the libraries which might contain it.  Check your WAR, EJB JAR or EAR prior to deployment and make sure a jar containing javax.xml.namespace.qname isn't being deployed as well which I'd think would cause the conflict.  Note, I'm a JBoss guy so I'm not familiar with WebLogic.  I also dont use Spring. If you still can't figure it out, update your question with the jars being deployed with your app.